# In git log --name-status, what does the T type ("file changed") mean?

Tags: git, git-log

`man git-log` in `--name-status` paragraph refers to `--diff-filter`, which, in turn, says that `T` is "Changed", and `M` is "Modified".

`man git-diff` says

> T: change in the type of the file.

I created a test repo.

- Changing file executable bit results in `M`.
- Deleting a file and creating a directory with the same name results in `D` and `A`.
- Replacing a text file with a binary file results in `M` again (I know that git evaluates file types on the fly, but it was worth trying).

So what does `T` "Changed" mean there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M` means that the content of the file has been `M`odified.
`T` means that the `T`ype of the file has been changed, e.g. it used to be a regular file, but has been changed into a symbolic link, etc.

Comment: Thank you, symlink test printed `T`. I only thought about changing file into a directory.

Comment: @VictorSergienko: Git doesn't *store* directories (it just creates them on demand when needed), so while there is such a thing as a directory/file conflict in practice, it doesn't show up in `git diff` output as there are never any directories at that level.